# why isn't my array.Count working

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a powershell script for the first time and somehow the array.Count or array.Length are both not working.

What am I doing wrong over here:

```
$array = @(
    "item1",
    "item2"
);

if($array.Count > 0) {
    Write-Host "true";
}

if($array.Length > 0) {
    Write-Host "true";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Comparison_Operators?view=powershell-5.1); `-gt` should be used, not `>`

Note that `Count` is an alias of `Length`. so will yield the same result. You can see this by running `$array | Get-Member`.

```
$array = @(
    "item1",
    "item2"
);

if($array.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "true";
}

if($array.Length -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "true";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! powershell is a strange language if you compare this with other languages xD

Comment: Compare with perl/csh/tcl and it won't seem too strange ;-)

Comment: But why isn't it giving some kind of error? I can't seem to find the powershell > operator? Isn't this code invalid?

Comment: @StuiterSlurf It can take some getting used to considering the mathematical symbols... I haven't used perl/csh/tcl so found it strange as first. The code `2 > 0` is valid, but it doesn't do what you think as `>`acts the [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Redirection?view=powershell-5.1). `2 < 0` will give an error: `The '<' operator is reserved for future use.`